# How do I find when a http request has been sent C#

Tags: c#, httprequest

`using System.Net.HttpClient;`

I have some code which needs to send http requests as fast as possible but I have to send them in the correct order, so I want to know when a request has been sent from this machine without waiting for a response from the server.

I am also fine with some requests going in the wrong order as it is fine to sacrifice a bit of accuracy for speed in this case. I say this because the only way to really assure that they go in a sequential order is to wait for the response, however it is fine if i just send the next after the last was sent as it would have a small chance of getting to the server before the one before it

This code is to automate my homework so each request represents one answer done, that is why it is not entirely necessary to get a few requests wrong.

This is also my first time using stack overflow so please tell me if I did something wrong.

```
StringContent requestContent = new StringContent(content, Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uri, requestContent); 

return response;
```

Comment: You need to use some logging mechanism to log the messages before doing `client.PostAsync`

Comment: If you don't need the response, then do not use `await`. Make sure though that your process does not end or, if you are in an asp.net app, that your request doesn't end before the last of your requests go out.

Comment: "I have some code which needs to send http requests **as fast as possible**" - then don't use C# + .NET and don't use `HttpClient` - instead use raw sockets or `HTTP.sys` directly.

Comment: Hi!  Your requirements seem a bit conflicting.  You have to send them in the correct order but you are also fine with some requests going in the wrong order?  Can you clarify?

Comment: What is the code for? What does it represent? That is just a single request.

Comment: Good point @Dai I will look into that instead

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to take [this](https://www.azurefromthetrenches.com/capturing-and-tracing-all-http-requests-in-c-and-net/) example of setting up an http event listener, and then in the proper event you want, like OnBeginHttpResponse, for example, make the call to fire the next request off.